# IBM Worklight console preview commmon resources link error: Not Found

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

Im encountering issues when try to preview my apps using 'Preview common Resoursces' at Worklight Console after deployment to Worklight Server (A physical server installed with Worklight)

Im getting below error:

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /*contextRoot*/apps/services/preview/*appName*/common/0 was not found in this server**

Does anyone have encountered and resolved the same issue?

p/s: I have deployed a new Worklight runtime environment in my Worklight server using Worklight Server Configuration Tool which I uploaded my project .war files and deployed it successfully. I have restart the service and when view in Worklight console the new runtime is there. Deployed .wlapp and .adapter successfully however cannot view the application at worklight console.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is totally confusing. First you mention the development server, which does mean localhost - your machine, in Eclipse, but then you mention "a physical server", and later on you mention using the server configuration tool which has got nothing to do with the development server... so which is, what are you doing, what are deploying, where are you deploying to. And you don't mention at all which version of Worklight you are using - there are more than 10 releases.

Comment: I have edited the post back. its actually i wanted to deploy the application that I have build from my local machine to a worklight server. The deployment of .war, .wlapp, and .adapter is success however I cannot view the deployed app using 'Preview as common resource' The worklight server version is 6.2

Comment: Can you please provide the messages.log file from the application server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preview server let is no longer present in server deployments to what is termed as "remote servers" (non-development servers == not Studio). In later fixes the preview button was removed.

In short, preview hours not be available in that server deployment environment.